# Scrolling a div from an outer div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Check out the small html structure sample below for context. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfrkK/28/) for and example of the problem.

Short explanation for fiddle users:

1. Scroll left - vertical scroll bar not visible
2. Scroll right - vertical visible
3. I want the vertical scroll bar always visible
4. Requirement - The header must remain fixed (visible while scrolling)

Long explanation:

I have a table with a fixed header and a scrollable body. The complexities of that requires two tables. That's all good. In my cause I also have resizable columns. `table-layout: fixed` for that to work. This is were problems arise.

To make the scrolling body work I've got a div that wraps the `.rows` table for scrolling. This works great until the grid, specifically the `.rows` table, overflows in the x direction. In this case the the vertical scroll bar is only visible if the grid is scrolled all the way to the right. Because the scroll bar is on the `.row-wrapper` div. And that overflow is being hidden by the `.grid` div. I'd like the scrollbar to be on the `.grid-canvas` div so that it is visible even when scrolled to the left side.

```
<div class=grid>
    <div class=grid-canvas>
        <table class=header></table>
        <div class=row-wrapper>
            <table class=rows></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

side note: If you set the table display to block then the wrapping div isn't needed unless you want to support IE8 which I do. Maybe there's a way around that but that another question for another time.

Comment: here is a good example of how u can have it done
http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: This does basically the same thing as what I'm getting. The issue still persists though. Overflow is set on the tbody so the scroll is happening on the tbody. When the table width is larger than the container width you see the same issue. The vertical scroll bar is not visible unless you scroll all the way to the right. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfrkK/63/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after hours of hacking with no luck I decided to disect some of the existing libraries to see how they were accomplishing this. Unfortunately I was sorely disappointed. All of them were using javascript.

The up side to this is that the it only requires a small bit of code not that that means it will perform well. To make this perform as well as possible I'm updating the header when required in the x direction. Since this will typically be a small area in my case it should be good enough.

Hundredth times a charm!

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfrkK/100/)

Here's the basic:

HTML

```
<div class=grid>
    <div class=grid-canvas>
        <div class=header-wrapper>
            <table class=header></table>
        </div>
        <div class=row-wrapper>
          <table class=rows></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$headerDiv = $('.header-wrapper');
$rowDiv = $('.row-wrapper');
$rowDiv.scroll(function(e) {
    $headerDiv.css({
        left: -$rowDiv[0].scrollLeft + 'px'
    });
});​
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
}

.grid-canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.row-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 18px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

th, td {
  width: 80px;
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

​

Comment: To make this work properly in IE I had to make a few more changes. The issue with my answer for IE is that the scrollbar will be hidden under the header div. This wasn't obvious in other browsers I was using because the scrollbar is transparent and it still sits on top of the header. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfrkK/104/).

Answer (score 1):

What about this one, If you want to use javascript/jQuery ?

```
$(function(){
    $("table").stickyTableHeaders();
});

/*! Copyright (c) 2011 by Jonas Mosbech - https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders
    MIT license info: https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/blob/master/license.txt */

;(function ($, window, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    var pluginName = 'stickyTableHeaders';
    var defaults = {
            fixedOffset: 0
        };

    function Plugin (el, options) {
        // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
        // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
        var base = this;

        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        // Cache DOM refs for performance reasons
        base.$window = $(window);
        base.$clonedHeader = null;
        base.$originalHeader = null;

        // Keep track of state
        base.isCloneVisible = false;
        base.leftOffset = null;
        base.topOffset = null;

        base.init = function () {
            base.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            base.$el.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);

                // remove padding on <table> to fix issue #7
                $this.css('padding', 0);

                $this.wrap('<div class="divTableWithFloatingHeader"></div>');

                base.$originalHeader = $('thead:first', this);
                base.$clonedHeader = base.$originalHeader.clone();

                base.$clonedHeader.addClass('tableFloatingHeader');
                base.$clonedHeader.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': 0,
                    'z-index': 1, // #18: opacity bug
                    'display': 'none'
                });

                base.$originalHeader.addClass('tableFloatingHeaderOriginal');

                base.$originalHeader.after(base.$clonedHeader);

                // enabling support for jquery.tablesorter plugin
                // forward clicks on clone to original
                $('th', base.$clonedHeader).click(function (e) {
                    var index = $('th', base.$clonedHeader).index(this);
                    $('th', base.$originalHeader).eq(index).click();
                });
                $this.bind('sortEnd', base.updateWidth);
            });

            base.updateWidth();
            base.toggleHeaders();

            base.$window.scroll(base.toggleHeaders);
            base.$window.resize(base.toggleHeaders);
            base.$window.resize(base.updateWidth);
        };

        base.toggleHeaders = function () {
            base.$el.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);

                var newTopOffset = isNaN(base.options.fixedOffset) ?
                    base.options.fixedOffset.height() : base.options.fixedOffset;

                var offset = $this.offset();
                var scrollTop = base.$window.scrollTop() + newTopOffset;
                var scrollLeft = base.$window.scrollLeft();

                if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + $this.height())) {
                    var newLeft = offset.left - scrollLeft;
                    if (base.isCloneVisible && (newLeft === base.leftOffset) && (newTopOffset === base.topOffset)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    base.$clonedHeader.css({
                        'top': newTopOffset,
                        'margin-top': 0,
                        'left': newLeft,
                        'display': 'block'
                    });
                    base.$originalHeader.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    base.isCloneVisible = true;
                    base.leftOffset = newLeft;
                    base.topOffset = newTopOffset;
                }
                else if (base.isCloneVisible) {
                    base.$clonedHeader.css('display', 'none');
                    base.$originalHeader.css('visibility', 'visible');
                    base.isCloneVisible = false;
                }
            });
        };

        base.updateWidth = function () {
            // Copy cell widths and classes from original header
            $('th', base.$clonedHeader).each(function (index) {
                var $this = $(this);
                var $origCell = $('th', base.$originalHeader).eq(index);
                this.className = $origCell.attr('class') || '';
                $this.css('width', $origCell.width());
            });

            // Copy row width from whole table
            base.$clonedHeader.css('width', base.$originalHeader.width());
        };

        // Run initializer
        base.init();
    }

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery, window);
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmosbech/stFcx/)

Sorry, i forgot from where i got it. but special thanks to him/her. And also the author i.e Jonas Mosbech.
Hope, it will helps you. Thanks. !!

Answer (score -1):

i edited your css and guess this is what you want:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
  width: 80px;
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid {
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;

  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid-canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}

.row-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  /* assumed height of the header */
  padding-top: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: The header grid is no longer fixed in that case. i.e. when you scroll down the header is no longer visible.

Comment: @user1447420: header should remains fixed even while you scroll vertically or horizontally and its not possible solution.

Comment: i think you add part4 after i send this answer.when i answer it was 3 rules.

Comment: Yes I did. I added part 4 for clarity. After seeing your response.