# Scrollable table both horizontally and vertically with fixed header

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I am looking for scrollable table. It works fine when width is fixed but it doesn't works while columns are created dynamically.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="325">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300" >
         <tr>
            <th>col 1 heading</th>
            <th>col 2 heading</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="width:325px; height:48px; overflow:auto;">
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300" >
           <tr>
             <td>col 1 data 1</td>
             <td>col 2 data 1</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>col 1 data 2</td>
             <td>col 2 data 2</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>col 1 data 3</td>
             <td>col 2 data 3</td>
           </tr>
         </table>  
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I found it from here http://www.scientificpsychic.com/blogentries/html-and-css-scrolling-table-with-fixed-heading.html

See demo

http://jsfiddle.net/u8yyD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's quite similar question that i answered.

```
$(function(){
    $("table").stickyTableHeaders();
});

/*! Copyright (c) 2011 by Jonas Mosbech - https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders
    MIT license info: https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/blob/master/license.txt */

;(function ($, window, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    var pluginName = 'stickyTableHeaders';
    var defaults = {
            fixedOffset: 0
        };

    function Plugin (el, options) {
        // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
        // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
        var base = this;

        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        // Cache DOM refs for performance reasons
        base.$window = $(window);
        base.$clonedHeader = null;
        base.$originalHeader = null;

        // Keep track of state
        base.isCloneVisible = false;
        base.leftOffset = null;
        base.topOffset = null;

        base.init = function () {
            base.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            base.$el.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);

                // remove padding on <table> to fix issue #7
                $this.css('padding', 0);

                $this.wrap('<div class="divTableWithFloatingHeader"></div>');

                base.$originalHeader = $('thead:first', this);
                base.$clonedHeader = base.$originalHeader.clone();

                base.$clonedHeader.addClass('tableFloatingHeader');
                base.$clonedHeader.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': 0,
                    'z-index': 1, // #18: opacity bug
                    'display': 'none'
                });

                base.$originalHeader.addClass('tableFloatingHeaderOriginal');

                base.$originalHeader.after(base.$clonedHeader);

                // enabling support for jquery.tablesorter plugin
                // forward clicks on clone to original
                $('th', base.$clonedHeader).click(function (e) {
                    var index = $('th', base.$clonedHeader).index(this);
                    $('th', base.$originalHeader).eq(index).click();
                });
                $this.bind('sortEnd', base.updateWidth);
            });

            base.updateWidth();
            base.toggleHeaders();

            base.$window.scroll(base.toggleHeaders);
            base.$window.resize(base.toggleHeaders);
            base.$window.resize(base.updateWidth);
        };

        base.toggleHeaders = function () {
            base.$el.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);

                var newTopOffset = isNaN(base.options.fixedOffset) ?
                    base.options.fixedOffset.height() : base.options.fixedOffset;

                var offset = $this.offset();
                var scrollTop = base.$window.scrollTop() + newTopOffset;
                var scrollLeft = base.$window.scrollLeft();

                if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + $this.height())) {
                    var newLeft = offset.left - scrollLeft;
                    if (base.isCloneVisible && (newLeft === base.leftOffset) && (newTopOffset === base.topOffset)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    base.$clonedHeader.css({
                        'top': newTopOffset,
                        'margin-top': 0,
                        'left': newLeft,
                        'display': 'block'
                    });
                    base.$originalHeader.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    base.isCloneVisible = true;
                    base.leftOffset = newLeft;
                    base.topOffset = newTopOffset;
                }
                else if (base.isCloneVisible) {
                    base.$clonedHeader.css('display', 'none');
                    base.$originalHeader.css('visibility', 'visible');
                    base.isCloneVisible = false;
                }
            });
        };

        base.updateWidth = function () {
            // Copy cell widths and classes from original header
            $('th', base.$clonedHeader).each(function (index) {
                var $this = $(this);
                var $origCell = $('th', base.$originalHeader).eq(index);
                this.className = $origCell.attr('class') || '';
                $this.css('width', $origCell.width());
            });

            // Copy row width from whole table
            base.$clonedHeader.css('width', base.$originalHeader.width());
        };

        // Run initializer
        base.init();
    }

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery, window);
```

see reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653315/scrolling-a-div-from-an-outer-div/13657760#13657760)

Comment: its nice example. i have spent lots of time to solve it. Thanks. !!

Answer (score 0):

The following is one way to keep the th and td aligned:

CSS:

```
.column1class { width:100px; } 
.column2class { width:200px; }
```

HTML after the table defining the headers and rows;

```
<colgroup>
<col class='column1class'>
<col class='column2class'>
</colgroup>
```