# HTML table with vertical and horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

There is a table in which the number of rows and columns to be displayed is not known in advance.That is generated in a JSP like

```
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <c:foreach col=${Dcol} >
      ...
     </c:foreach>
   </tr>
   </thead>
```

i.e width of the columns isn't fixed

When scrolling horizontally the header row should scroll horizontally.

When scrolling vertically the header row should remain fixed.

Although there is a solution here [Scrollable table both horizontally and vertically with fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666989/scrollable-table-both-horizontally-and-vertically-with-fixed-header)

I would like to know if i can use two separate tables (Table1 for header row and Table2 for all other rows) and synchronize their horizontal scrolling by binding a horizontal scroll event on second table to call a function which scrolls first table horizontally.
Can this be done through simple javascript as a table has only an onscroll event and no event for specific direction of scroll?

Please provide any plain javascript solution or sequence of steps.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:absolute` on a `window.onscroll` event and determine for `window.pageYOffset` or `document.body.scrollTop`, like:

```
//first the CSS
#headerContainer{
  padding:0; position:relative; overflow:visible;
}
#header{
  margin:0; padding:0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:99;
}
//now the JavaScript
var win = window, doc = document, bod = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
var pT = 0;
function nice(elementId, offsetParentTop){
  var hs = E(elementId).style;
  var sy = win.pageYOffset || bod.scrollTop;
  if(sy !== pT){
    pT = sy+offsetParentTop;
    hs.top = pT+'px';
  }
}
onscroll = function(){
  nice('header', 30);
}
```

You could use a series of `Element.offsetTop` attributes to determine your `offsetParentTop` argument. It really depends how deep you have your header.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how do i implement this in the HTML? And this seems to me that table header will remain fixed on page scrolling.The header should be fixed on scrolling of table's vertical scroll bars

Comment: You put a `<script type='text/javascript' src='wherever.js'></script>` at the bottom of your HTML page, right before the `</body>` tag. I'm not going to do you CSS for you, but I created a working Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/89sXK/ . You might want to consider a floating layout instead of a table. Look it up.

Comment: Thanks for your approach but if i am able to implement it correctly the alignment of column breaks as the number of columns increase and the header is fixed with respect to vertical scrolling of the page.I found a jquery implementation here where different columns could be of different width http://jsfiddle.net/jmosbech/stFcx/