# css: table scrollable both horizontally and vertically with fixed header

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I implement a table that is both horizontally and vertically scrollable with fixed header using css?

I found this [Scrolling a div from an outer div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653315/scrolling-a-div-from-an-outer-div/13657760#13657760), but it is implemented by using Javascript/Jquery. Any way to implement it by using only CSS?

The updated code:

```
#div-table-content {
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
font-size: 12px;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
}

tbody {
height: 400px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

thead tr {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/)

Answer (score 3):

For a start divide your `<table>` semantically to headers inside `<thead>` and content inside `<tbody>`.

Then, for vertical scrolling, give a fixed height to your `<tbody>` and set `overflow-y: auto` and `display: block`.

For horizontal scrolling, I belive you have to wrap your entire table with a container (lets say `<div>` and give it a fixed width and `overflow-x: auto`.

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/tZnN9/)

Comment: but what about the horizontal scrollable?

Comment: How would you like the horizontal scrolling to behave? The headers are scrolling horizontally too? Do you need a fixed first-column or something?

Comment: yes, the headers need scrolling horizontally too, I don't need a fixed first-column

Comment: @JoshC I updated my css code, and the result is: the div is horizontally scrollable with the header, the tbody is both vertically and horizontally scrollable and the width of the tbody is equal to the size of the first column of the header.

Comment: @Cacheing I've added a jsFiddle with the minimum of changes needed for this to work.

Comment: @JoshC your example is exactly what I want, I am trying to figuring out what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @Cacheing you're confusing the kind Josh C with me :) I've tried to keep the required styles minimal (except of borders and background colors).

Comment: @Itay ummm, sorry about that.

Comment: @Itay I updated my css code, but I am still having problem. The problem is that the header is not lined up with the body. I mean the width of tbody is not equal to theader, do you know why?

Comment: @Itay it seems that the `thead` and `tbody` are pretty separated. The width of the `thead` and `tbody` is separately set according to their content. Since the `tbody`'s content is shorter than that of the `thead`, they are not lined up.

Comment: @Itay your code suffers from the same problem. See if you modify the header name to be much longer and add `white-space:nowrap;` to `table`'s css.

Comment: @Cacheing I know there are problems with this solution. You should remembers it's really not a natural thing for a table to "broken" like that.

Comment: @Itay do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Cacheing My suggestion is my fiddle. More generic stuff will probably require using JS or a really coupled CSS.

Comment: The fiddle is close to what I'm looking for, but I'd like the vertical scrollbar to be visible all the time. In the fiddle, you have to scroll all the way to the right in order to see the vertical scrollbar, which is awkward if you want to vertically scroll while viewing the first column of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal and vertical scrolling with sticky column headers using css only can be done with the following.

1. A container div with `overflow: scroll`
2. A `thead` with `position: sticky` and `inset-block-start: 0;`

Full example below:

```css
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 180px;
  width: 300px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th,
table td {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table thead {
  position: sticky;
  inset-block-start: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Fruits</th>
        <th>Nuts</th>
        <th>Vegetables</th>
        <th>Meats</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Peanut</td>
        <td>Carrot</td>
        <td>Chicken</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td>Pecan</td>
        <td>Potato</td>
        <td>Pork</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cherry</td>
        <td>Cashew</td>
        <td>Tomato</td>
        <td>Beef</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Almond</td>
        <td>Cabbage</td>
        <td>Lamb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kiwi</td>
        <td>Brazil Nut</td>
        <td>Onion</td>
        <td>Chicken</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lemon</td>
        <td>Hazelnut</td>
        <td>Cucumber</td>
        <td>Fish</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fake table with css-grid (if you don't mind).

```
.table {
  display: grid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: auto;

  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
}

.head {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  grid-row: 1;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Than you put all cells into single element

```
  <div class="table">
    <div class="head">column 1</div>
    <div class="head">column 2</div>
    <div class="head">column 3</div>
    <div>data - column 1 - row 1</div>
    <div>data - column 2 - row 1</div>
    <div>data - column 3 - row 1</div>
    <div>data - column 1 - row 2</div>
    <div>data - column 2 - row 2</div>
    <div>data - column 3 - row 2</div>
    <div>data - column 1 - row 3</div>
    <div>data - column 2 - row 3</div>
    <div>data - column 3 - row 3</div>
  </div>
```

Now you can see both scrollbars all the time; header scrolls horizontally but not vertically.